# from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField ImportError: No module named 'imagekit.models'

Tags: python, django

Django ==1.8.6. i Have installe pip install imagekit. imagekit==1.0.6. modells.py

```
import PIL
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit, Adjust,ResizeToFill
```

the wrote model names. when i wanted to migrate the cmd showed me an error:  from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField ImportError: No module named 'imagekit.models'

Comment: May be my answer here will help somebody: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70141791/9323890

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this problem recently. The issue is likely that you installed `imagekit` instead of `django-imagekit`; those are two different packages and you want the latter.

Try `pip uninstall imagekit` followed by `pip install django-imagekit`.

Answer (score 1):

Install django-imagekit:

```
pip install django-imagekit
```

Use ImageKit, instead of imagekit:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  "ImageKit"
  ...
]
...
from ImageKit.models import ProcessedImageField
```

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of ImageKit says you should also add imagekit to you INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py after installing it using pip.

Comment: i have added to settings.py. after that i got an error