# from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagekit'

Tags: python, django

I have ran into the above error even though i've ran

pip install django-imagekit

phoneshop/models.py:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:products_by_category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                processors=[ResizeToFill(90, 90)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 60})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)#
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:prod_detail', args=[str(self.category.slug), str(self.slug)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Both "from"'s in the imagekit imports are underlined saying no name in module ImageKit

I've imported the correct imagekit and tried uninstalling as i know there's 2 variations. So I'm stuck and need some help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Output of pip freeze:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
cycler==0.10.0
Django==3.1.7
django-appconf==1.0.4
django-bootstrap-breadcrumbs==0.9.2
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2
django-imagekit==4.0.2
idna==2.10
Image-Kit==0.0.3
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.20.1
pilkit==2.0
Pillow==8.1.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
scipy==1.6.2
six==1.15.0
slug==2.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
stripe==2.56.0
urllib3==1.26.4
```

Comment: Can you add to your answer the output of `pip freeze` - if imagekit really is installed, could you check that the installation ran without errors or warnings. Imagekit might require additional python libs like Pillow and additional packages to be installed on the underlying host system.

Comment: Added pip freeze output

Answer (score 0):

I am using the VSCode and in my case I forced to reopen my editor/IDE to make it resolved(found).